# pass a value from one makefile target to another

Tags: makefile

I have two targets in makefile

```
.ONESHELL:
clean:
    #clean something
    # How to clean $loopback ?

.ONESHELL:
work:
    #...
    #loopback=$(losetup -f) || true
```

execution sequence is :
work -> clean

so how do I pass the loopback variable for the clean: target ?

Comment: `make work` is one command, `make clean` is another command -
just like `gcc foo.c` is one command and `gcc bar.c` is another.
So if you want one command to know information that you generate by an
another command, how might you do it?

Comment: o write it to a tmp file or something ? Thats ugly isnt it?

Comment: If its too ugly you will have to invent another method
of passing information between processes that are not running at the same time :)
It may well be that `make` - which is primarily for building software -
is not the right tool for your job.

Comment: I can live with tmp file solution. Wondering if there are more answers

Comment: There are other ways to do it. For example, you could have the `work` recipe call `make clean`, and pass it the variable.

Comment: Is `clean` dependent on `work` somewhere in your file?   A temporary file might be your best bet for this.   Another solution is to make loopback be a make variable (as opposed to a bash one within the recipe), so you could have `loopback:=$(shell losetup -f)` in your global scope, and use that in your recipes.  Notice though, that this command would always be run, even if you're not building work or clean.